# Download Elasticsearch indices in local machine?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, scripting, elasticsearch-plugin

We have elasticsearch for storing kibana logs. The server is getting full day by day hence I would like to download the indices and push them to S3 bucket. 
I have already written a script to push them in S3 but unable to download multiple indices in local.

If someone could explain in detail or gave example of downloading those indices would be helpful.

Comment: `"download the indices"` - you mean pull all data from every index?

Comment: Yes, our every index contains around 400-500MB of data. Hence I need to download all those indices somewhere (perhaps on some server) and then after downloading need to push them to S3 bucket.

Comment: Are you looking for snapshot and restore? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: Maybe [Scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)